# Clipping background of span

Tags: html, css, sass

So i am tasked with creating a `<span>` element with the background that does not cover the entire text. Like this: [image]  It should stop about halfway up the text. Is there any way to do this?

I have investigated using `:after` pseudo element to no luck, and wondering if this is possible with css. I am fairly limited on wrapping the span in another element but let me know if this is the solve

**CSS**

```
span {
  @include blog-styles;
  background-color: $yellow;
}
```

NOTE: The span will be multiline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```css
span {
     background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff 50%, #ffff00 50%);
}
```

```html
<span>Hello<br>Hi</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this?

```
 span {
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, yellow 50%, #fff 50%);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3f5b48xy/

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
span {
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff 50%, yellow 50%); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```